# How to save relationships in entity with angular

Tags: angularjs, foreign-keys, jhipster

I'm using AngularJS with JHipster to develop an application. I have two entities with a relationship bewteen them: `Demandelettre` and `Etudiant`. I need to save manually the Etudiant entitie key to the Demandelettre entitie, but I get some errors when I try to make it.

I need to replace that one by an input text to save input value to other entitie like id for relationship.

```
<div class="form-group">
        <label for="field_etudiant">Etudiant</label>
        <select class="form-control" id="field_etudiant" name="etudiant" ng-model="vm.demandelettre.etudiant" ng-options="etudiant as etudiant.matricule for etudiant in vm.etudiants track by etudiant.id">
            <option value=""></option>
        </select>
    </div>
```

This is the default `save` method in the `Demandelettre` Controller :

```
function save () {
        vm.isSaving = true;
        if (vm.demandelettre.id !== null) {
            vm.demandelettre.etattraitement = 1;
            Demandelettre.update(vm.demandelettre, onSaveSuccess, onSaveError);
        } else {
            vm.demandelettre.datedemande = Date.now() ,'yyyy-MM-dd' ;
            vm.demandelettre.etattraitement = 0;
            Demandelettre.save(vm.demandelettre, onSaveSuccess, onSaveError);
        }
    }
```

Does anyone have a solution to save manually this foreign key in the entitie ?
Sorry for my english (if poor). Thank you in advance.

Comment: What are the errors that are returned to you ? Give us more details about it.

Comment: Thank's Sir. The default method with options works good. But I need to save manually the foreign key in the other table. And when I try I have this error :

Error :
JSON parse error: Can not construct instance of org.uasz.cri.domain.Etudiant: no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('233');

Comment: By default, jhipster get data in options and add them to other table. But in my application, I need to get data from input text and to save that on to the other table. I dont know how they do to save automaticaly the foreign key.

Comment: Not sure I understand your question, you talk about foreign keys but JHipster works at object level so it's rather about relationships. Please edit your question rather than adding details into comments. Why do you use a string for an id? It should be a number, this could be why you get this JSON error.

Comment: Thank's for your response. I try to learn JHipster and AngularJS. Sorry for the mistake, it's about relationships, I will edit my question to give more informations. By default, when I created two entities Etudiant and Demandelettre. In Demandelettre HTML page, JHipster show in option matricule values from Etudiant entity. And when I save data, Etudiant entity id is push in Demandelettre entity. Now I need to remove that option to let user write this value in a textbox. But I dont know how to save that relationship in Demandelettre and I don't undertand the way JHipster make that one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found answer for my question. You can watch this video for more details. Link : https://youtu.be/pfK6njKkr0w

I create class `DemandelettreEtudiantDao` and I put inside :

```
package org.uasz.cri.web.rest;

import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.uasz.cri.security.SecurityUtils;

@Component

public class DemandelletreEtudiantDao {
    private final JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
    public DemandelletreEtudiantDao(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate){
        this.jdbcTemplate=jdbcTemplate;
    }
    public long getEtudiantIdByCurrentLogin(){
        String sql="select id from etudiant where email='"+ SecurityUtils.getCurrentUserLogin()+"'";
        System.out.println("Id Etudiant"+sql);
        return this.jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(sql, long.class);
    }

}
```

In DemandelettreResource.java I call the DemandelletreEtudiantDao class method :

```
// Call DemandelletreEtudiantDao class method
    private UserRepository userRepository;
    private DemandelletreEtudiantDao demandelletreEtudiantDao;
    private EtudiantRepository etudiantRepository;

// Class constructor
    @Autowired
    public DemandelettreResource(
            DemandelettreRepository demandelettreRepository,
            UserRepository userRepository,
            EtudiantRepository etudiantRepository,
            DemandelletreEtudiantDao demandelletreEtudiantDao) {
        super();
        this.demandelettreRepository = demandelettreRepository;
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
        this.etudiantRepository = etudiantRepository;
        this.demandelletreEtudiantDao = demandelletreEtudiantDao;
    }

// over post method
        demandelettre.setEtudiant(etudiantRepository.findOne(demandelletreEtudiantDao.getEtudiantIdByCurrentLogin()));
```